# How to filter query objects by date range in DRF?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I have simple model:

**models.py**

```
class Report(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    created_date = models.DateField()
```

Created **filters.py** file and using **django-filters** package wrote FilterSet:

```
from .models import Report

class ReportFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    created_date = django_filters.DateFromToRangeFilter()
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = ['created_date']
```

Simple **views.py**:

```
from .filters import ReportFilter
from .models import Report

def Reports(request):
    reports = Report.objects.all()
    myFilter = ReportFilter(request.GET, queryset=reports)
    reports = myFilter.qs
    return render(request, 'dashboard/index.html', {'reports': reports, 'myFilter': myFilter})
```

And the last file **index.html**:

```
{% block content %}

<form method="get" style="display: block; width: 335px; margin: 20px auto;">
    {{myFilter.form}}
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

{% if reports %}
    {% for report in reports %}
        <tr>
            <td>
                {{ report.title }}
            </td>
            <td>
                {{ report.created_date }}
            </td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
 {% endif %}
</table>

{% endblock content %}
```

**Question in short**: *How to do it DRF?* (beginner in DRF)

What I tried so far:

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Report

class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Report
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
from .filters import ReportFilter
from .serializers import ReportSerializer
from rest_framework import viewsets
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend
from .models import Report

class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend,]
    filterset_class = ReportFilter
```

Did not change **filters.py** and added all additions to settings.py file (when installed django-filter and etc.), but NO LUCK ;(

Help, please...

============================================

UPDATED:

**views.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers
fom .views import ReportViewSet

r = routers.DefaultRouter()
r.register(r'^report/$', ReportViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
   path('', include(r.urls))
]
```

Comment: How are you sending filter request? Are you sending filter request like this, ```api/reports/?created_date_after=2022-01-01&created_date_before=2022-03-01 ``` ?

Comment: Yeap, sorry forgot to add urls.py file, i will update my question by adding urls.py file now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a simple way you can override [.filter_queryset](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#custom-generic-filtering) method and use the [range](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#range) lookup to filter dates.

views.py

```py
class ReportViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Report.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ReportSerializer

    def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
        date_after = self.request.GET.get('date_after', None)
        date_before = self.request.GET.get('date_before', None)
        if date_after and date_before:
            queryset = queryset.filter(created_date__range=[date_after, date_before])
        return super().filter_queryset(queryset)
```

endpoint

```
http://localhost:8000/reports/?date_after=yyyy-mm-dd&date_before=yyyy-mm-dd
```

Or, use one of the listed [Third party packages](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#third-party-packages). Personally I have tried [django-rest-framework-filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters), but the project is not updated since 2020 and that will cause problems with the latest versions of Django due to the removal of some packages.